# How to get detailed CSS info for an element in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, phantomjs

I want to basically be able to build what Chrome has in their Developer Tools under Styles in their Elements tab. Is there a way to get this kind of detailed CSS info for an element in PhantomJS?

For example, I'd like to know that a `<div>` has a `color` of `red` due to an internal stylesheet at line number 5. And that overrides a `color` of `purple` that was set in the external stylesheet `index.css` at line 43.

As another example, here's the Style tab in Chrome for the "Ask Question" button on this page:
[image]

Comment: Sounds cool. What's your question?

Comment: @Phil - question is the title: "How to get detailed CSS info for an element in PhantomJS?"

Comment: For starters, there's [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) however that's not going to tell you where the styles come from. As it stands, this question is too broad. Is there a specific part you're struggling with?

Comment: I'm well aware of `getComputedStyle`, I need to know why a style was applied to an element. Where did that CSS setting come from?